# How to include third party library or some CDN's in production mode angular2 CLI ?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

As far as i know when we run the project in the production mode angular will create one bundle file named as commonly main.js which includes all the js files from the dist folder including dependencies like angular,RxJs etc....

Now my problem is i am using CDN for jQuery and one seprate js file named xyz.js whihc is in my public folder, and i put the entry for both xyz.js and CDN in index.html file but these files not getting included and throw error `not found` while running the project.

upto my knowledge at the time of production mode all entry's of index.html are ignored then where i have to define those files ?

errors are like

```
$ is not defined

http://localhost:4200/abc/XYZ.js --not found
```

at the time of errors project gets crash :(

what should i do ?

Comment: You could just update index.html after `ng build --prod`. Not a long-term solution, but should do until CLI is polished (;

Comment: still not working @Sasxa

Comment: How come the CDN is not working?

Comment: Even i get surprised why CDN is not working :(